# How to make programs compiled under Dev C++ smaller?

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-construction, dev-c++

I'm using version 5.4.0 and simplest program (empty screen) have almost one megabyte.
For example, after compilation this below simple program has 1 276 KB. But deleting #include makes file really small : 27 KB.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum(int a){
    if(a>1) 
        return sum(a-1)+a;
    else
        return 1;
}

int main(){

    int a=1;

    while(a>=0){
        cout<<"a = ";
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"1+...+a = "<<sum(a)<<endl;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

It seems to me that it should be possible to generate a much smaller executable for the above. How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Could you provide the code for this "simplest program" then?

Comment: there must be some linker options. make every library shared

Comment: are you using the directive WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas from my experience:

### Dead Code

Review all source code and remove unused code, both unused functions and statement blocks that will not be executed.  Use a static code analyzer to assist in finding them.

### Printf

Don't use `printf` unless necessary.
It hauls in a lot of code, especially for formatting floating point numbers.

### Linking in Unused functions

Does your compiler haul in unused functions from library files?
Some compilers link in the whole library file rather than only the functions used from it.

### Debug vs. Release metrics

Are you measuring debug (with symbols) or release (no symbols)?
Are you measuring the static library version or only code without dynamic libraries?

### Inline functions

Review any inline functions.
Convert larger inline functions to not inline.

### Templates

Remove common code out of templates and into functions.

### Static & Global Initialized variables

Reduce the number of statically and globally initialized variables.
The initialization takes up space in your executable.
Declare constant variables as `static const` wherever possible.

### Strings and Text

Place common text literals into one file and return references or constant pointers to them.
This will assist the compiler in merging duplicate strings across modules.

### Common code fragments

Analyze functions for common code fragments.  Factor them into separate functions or methods.

### Dynamic Libraries

Move some functionality into dynamic libraries.  Let the OS determine when to use the code.

### Future functionality

Remove all code related to future functionality that is not currently executed.

### Move data to data file

Data takes up room in your executable, especially values used for initializing static or global variables.  Consider moving the data to a file and loading the data on demand.

---

Some of these suggestions will shrink your executable but not the application, such as data files and dynamic libraries.  They will be required for your program to execute but may not be needed in the executable.

Some suggestions will slow the performance of your application.  Sorry, it's the *time/memory tradeoff*:  you can save memory but it will take more execution time (such as packing fields).